# Socket bind() working with unavailable address

Tags: c, sockets, bind, icmp

When I am trying to bind an unavailable address to an icmp socket like something which is not assigned to any interface, it binds to it without throwing any error. Am I doing something wrong?

```
if (c->pc_saddr.ps_len == sizeof(saddr.sin_addr.s_addr)) {

    bzero(&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
    saddr.sin_len = sizeof(saddr);
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy(c->pc_saddr.ps_data, &saddr.sin_addr.s_addr,
          c->pc_saddr.ps_len);

    /*
     * note: if bind fails, just log it & let the kernel decide on the
     * source address to use.
     */
    if (bind(icmp_socket.ps_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) != 0) {

        trace(TRACEFLAG_GENERAL, "%s: bind failed icmp: %s",
                   __FUNCTION__, strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

Comment: Define 'unavailable'.

Comment: As I said earlier, something which is a valid IP address of 32 bits but is not assigned to any local interface. Hence unavailable.

Comment: Normally it should fail and set errno to EADDRNOTAVAIL. If you run Linux, perhaps your machine has set an option enabling non-local binds, see [here](http://linux-ip.net/html/adv-nonlocal-bind.html).